# Design pattern for converting one model to another

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am writing a library in java and I need to convert (map) one model to another and vice versa. What I did was implementing an abstract converter class with 2 generic types, containing convertTo and convertFrom methods, and extended my converters from it.

```
public abstract class TypeConverter<MyType, OtherLibType> {
    private final Function<MyType, OtherLibType> fromMyType;
    private final Function<OtherLibType, MyType> fromOtherLibType;

    public TypeConverter(final Function<MyType, OtherLibType> fromMyType,
                         final Function<OtherLibType, MyType> fromOtherLibType
    ) {
        this.fromMyType = fromMyType;
        this.fromOtherLibType = fromOtherLibType;
    }

    public final OtherLibType convertFromMyType(final MyType myType) {
        return fromMyType.apply(myType);
    }

    public final MyType convertFromJspritType(final OtherLibType otherLibType) {
        return fromOtherLibType.apply(otherLibType);
    }

}
```

But for specific implementations I also may need other objects for converting and I don't know what is the best practice to implement such things. I thought about adapter and facade but they don't seem to match my requirements. Is there a design pattern that I could use for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should really declare this as an interface `Converter<T,R>`. It's also not clear to me why it's abstract since it seems to do all it's supposed to, given it has the two functions, so it should just straighforward implement that interface.

Comment: Looks like you might be trying to do the same thing as [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be an interface like

```
interface Converter<T, R> {
 R convertTo(T source, R target);
 T convertFrom(R source, T target);
}
```

Your abstract class would not need to be abstract and straight implement this interface by calling the `Function`s.

Then you can have a Wrapper that also implements that interface and delegates its called to the wrapped implementations.

```
class ConverterWrapper<T, I, R> implements Converter<T, R> {
 private Converter<T, I> toIntermediate;
 private Converter<I, R> toResult;

 // add trivial constructor to initialize the fields

 public R convertTo(T source) {
  I intermediate = toIntermediate.convertTo(source);
  return toResult.convert(intermediate);
 }
 public T convertFrom(R source) {
  I intermediate = toResult.convertFrom(source);
  return toIntermediate.convertFrom(intermediate);
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you ! but what about objects that I need to use in conversions, how can i pass these values from outside?